# Wine Prefix Creation Aborted

Tags: wine

I'm installing a windows program on a mac with Wine, When I try to install I get the error **Prefix Creation Aborted** and the following log:

```
###BOTTLING### default.sh`
###BOTTLING### Gathering debug Info...

Versions
OS...........................: darwin13
Wine.........................: 1.6.1
WineBottler..................: 1.6.1

Environment
PWD..........................: '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin'
PATH.........................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
USER.........................: stepharr
HOME.........................: /Users/stepharr
BUNDLERESOURCEPATH...........: /Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources
WINEPATH.....................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH..............: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/usr/lib
FONTCONFIG_FILE..............: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
SILENT.......................: -q
http_proxy...................: 
https_proxy..................: 
ftp_proxy....................: 
socks5_proxy.................: 

Bottle
TEMPLATE.....................: 
BOTTLE.......................: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app
INSTALLER_URL................: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/instmsia.exe
INSTALLER_IS_ZIPPED..........: 0
INSTALLER_NAME...............: instmsia.exe
INSTALLER_ARGUMENTS..........: 
WINETRICKS_ITEMS.............:  vcrun6
DLL_OVERRIDES................: 
EXECUTABLE_PATH..............: winefile
EXECUTABLE_ARGUMENTS.........: 
EXECUTABLE_VERSION...........: 1.0
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER............: com.yourcompany.yourapp
SILENT.......................: -q

Hardware:

Hardware Overview:

  Model Name: Mac Pro
  Model Identifier: MacPro3,1
  Processor Name: Quad-Core Intel Xeon
  Processor Speed: 2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 2
  Total Number of Cores: 8
  L2 Cache (per Processor): 12 MB
  Memory: 8 GB
  Bus Speed: 1.6 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: MP31.006C.B05
  SMC Version (system): 1.25f4
  Serial Number (system): G8848347XYK
  Hardware UUID: F9A6E8E1-69FE-5486-AFEE-BA270947CCC0

###BOTTLING### Create .app...
mkdir: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/main.nib:     Read-only file system
mkdir: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/MacOS/: Read-only file system
    /Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh:     line 217: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Resources/Credits.html: Read-only file system
ditto: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Resources/Winetricks.app: Read-only file     system
/Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh:     line 223: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/MacOS/startwine: Read-only file system
chmod: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/MacOS/startwine: No such file or directory
/Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh:     line 290: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Info.plist: Read-only file system
###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
wine: chdir to /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Resources/wineprefix
 : No such file or directory
### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit         /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 1.


Task returned with status 1.`
```

I'm wondering if there is a winetrick I have to run in order to install the program?

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem with winetrick. Did you read the error message? It says:

> mkdir: /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/main.nib:     Read-only file system

The sentence

> Read-only file system

is repeated a few times, until of course we are told that:

> chdir to /Volumes/REA's TESTware/B Law.app/Contents/Resources/wineprefix
>    : No such file or directory

which occurs because the filesystem being read-only, no files or directories can be created .

You have to deal with the fact you cannot write onto this disk. You may get around that perhaps by running the same program as root. If that fails, you will have to investigate read/write permissions in these folders, or perhaps the disk. But I believe the first option (running the install program as sudo) will fix your problem.